# python kivy TextInput on_click

Tags: python, kivy

Как привязать функцию к клику(тапу) по TextInput?

on_click не работает

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

class root(BoxLayout):
    pass

class app(App):
    def build(self):
        self.title = "Cr"
        return root()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app().run()



#:kivy 1.10.1

<root>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    size_hint: None, None
    width: 200
    height: 200
    TextInput:
        id: text_1st
        text:"login"
        on_click:
            self.text = ""

    TextInput:
        id: text_2nd
        text:"password"

    Button:
        id: btn_2nd
        text: "autorize"

    Button:
        id: btn_3rd
        text: "pass recovery"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в kivy нет события `on_click`, есть событие `on_press`, но оно не работает для `textInput`, вы можете заменит `on_click: self.text = ''` на `on_double_tap: self.text = ''`, но это событие срабатывает только при двойном нажитии, вместо этого вы можете использовать `on_focus`, но это событие срабатывает и при входе и при выходе из текстового поля, поэтому реализовать его можно как-то так:

```
on_focus: if self.focus: self.text = ""
```

т.к. kv lang поддерживает простые действия, то мы проверяем событие клика, если мы вошли в текстовое поле, то оно передается как `True`, если мы вышли, то оно передается как `False`, и событие не происходит

Comment: А если свой текстинпут сделать и в него событие добавить on_touch_down?